# easyui add entire column

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i'm currently using easyui datagrid, i just need to add entire column in a data grid and put them in a textbox or someting
[add debit and credit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnYdx.png)

[image]

i just need to add them then display and compare
also is it posible to do using php?
thanks in advance :)
i tried asking in their forums but but it seems they are not accepting any members anymore.
i also tried using this

```
$.post('show_details.php', {v: row.checkvou});
        $('#sd').form('load',row);
```

i was hoping i'll be able to get the value of 'checkvou' and just make a new function to add and compare it but no such luck as you see in the pic it says 'undefined index'
as for that '1231231' inside the textbox it is only displayed using javascipt

edit: or atleast help me get the value of that text box to a php variable here is the code of the text box:

```
<input name="checkvou" id="checkv" class="easyui-textbox"  ></input>
```

that would be very helpful also :D

Comment: DId you try `$('#checkv').textbox('getValue')`? Post the javascript code that you are working, then it would be easier to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wow i actually forgot to come back here to post how did i solved this, sorry bout that... anyway...

my solution to this is that i created another file then included it

```
include "dc_compute.php";
```

reason to this is that i found out that you cannot pass a javascript variable to php (that is why `$('#checkv').textbox('getValue')` did not work for me ( thanks Mawia HL for this suggestion))
then inside that file there is a function that get the data from the database and do the computaion thing then return the results, to make things clear here are the codes:

```
include "dc_compute.php";
$data = compute($_REQUEST['checkvou']); // $_REQUEST['checkvou'] is where the value of the textbox '#checkv' came from
```

dc_compute.php:

```
function compute($itemid){

    include 'conn.php';
    $debcred = array();
    //echo $itemid;
    $query1 = "SELECT * FROM editlist WHERE checkvou = '".$itemid."'";
    $query1_run = mysql_query($query1);
    //echo $query1_run;
    $deb = 0;
    $cred = 0;
    $qty = 0;
    while ($num = mysql_fetch_assoc($query1_run)) {
        // this is the part where it does the adding thing
        $deb += $num['debit'];
        $cred += $num['credit'];
    }

    array_push($debcred, $deb,$cred);
    return $debcred;
}
```

then at the end its just a simple if condition to know if they are balanced or not :D in the end this is how it looks:

```
include "dc_compute.php";
$data = compute($_REQUEST['checkvou']);

    if ($data[0] != $data[1]){

        ?>
        <h1 style="font-size: 20px; color:#8A0707">UNBALANCED CHEQUE!!</h1>

        <?php 
    }
```

[this is what the output look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeRa4.png)

i know, i know it is NOT THE BEST answer there is but this worked for me, if you guys have any suggestion i'm all ears :D